Issue: AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_NOTIFY_POLICY'
An issue occurred after installing a package named "camelot-py". When I run a boto3 script there occurred an AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute. I have upgraded "pyopenssl" and "cryptography" but still error occurs.
Versions:
boto3 = 1.26.138
cryptography = 2.1.4
pyOpenSSL = 17.5.0

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/forge/scripts/cgi-scripts/check_boto.py", line 1, in <module>
    import boto3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 26, in <module>
    import botocore.client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 15, in <module>
    from botocore import waiter, xform_name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 18, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.docstring import WaiterDocstring
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/docs/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.service import ServiceDocumenter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/docs/service.py", line 14, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.client import ClientDocumenter, ClientExceptionsDocumenter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/docs/client.py", line 17, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.example import ResponseExampleDocumenter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/docs/example.py", line 13, in <module>
    from botocore.docs.shape import ShapeDocumenter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/docs/shape.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.utils import is_json_value_header
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 37, in <module>
    import botocore.httpsession
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 45, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 50, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.crypto
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1550, in <module>
    class X509StoreFlags(object):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1568, in X509StoreFlags
    NOTIFY_POLICY = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_NOTIFY_POLICY
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_NOTIFY_POLICY'. Did you mean: 'X509_V_FLAG_EXPLICIT_POLICY'?`

